# Running a ASP.NET 4 app in .NET 2.0 app pool

Tags: asp.net, iis

I recently upgraded a .NET 2.0 app to .NET 4 and everything works great.

When I setup IIS I selected .NET 2.0 under the ASP.NET tab in IIS 6.

The app runs fine but I get these intermittent ViewState errors.

Could the IIS setup be causing the ViewState issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because view state in .Net 4 uses a different algorithm than earlier

> ASP.NET uses both encryption and hashing algorithms to help secure
> data such as forms authentication cookies and view state. By default,
> ASP.NET 4 now uses the HMACSHA256 algorithm for hash operations on
> cookies and view state. Earlier versions of ASP.NET used the older
> HMACSHA1 algorithm.

[ASP.NET 4 Breaking Changes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes)

You need to register .Net Framework 4.0 in IIS, then run your site under Application pool for .Net 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to register 4.0 framework, This link will help you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx